# using the split function to parse through a comma separated line

Tags: vb.net

solved it on my own ...

```
  int1 = CInt(line.Split(CChar(","))(1))
```

To read the contents of a text file, line by line, i am using this code

```
    Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("0trace2.txt")
        Dim line As String
        line = r.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            list.Add(line)
            line = r.ReadLine
            MsgBox(line)

        Loop
    End Using
```

however, the file has 4 comma separated values, all numbers. I need to extract each number as an integer. i tried the split method but i ran into an error

```
Dim int1 as Integer
Dim int2 as Integer
Dim int3 as Integer
Dim int4 as Integer

    Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("0trace2.txt")
        Dim line As String
        line = r.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            list.Add(line)
            line = r.ReadLine
           'MsgBox(line)
           int1 = CInt(line.Split(CChar(","))(1))

        Loop
    End Using
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean each line has 4 comma separated integers?

Comment: What was the error you ran into?

Comment: Also, if it's a multiline file where do you plan to store integers from every line?

Comment: `line.Split(",")` will parse a line into an array you can get the values from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you simple need to collect integers from a file with a structure like

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

you can use List(Of Integer) to collect them all, e.g.:

```
Dim arr As New List(Of Integer)

Do While (Not line Is Nothing)

   For Each s In line.split(",")
        arr.Add(s)
   Next 

   line = r.ReadLine
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier approach would be something like:

```
Dim IntList = Line.Split(","c).ToList.ConvertAll(Function(x) CInt(x))
```

or use linq

```
Dim IntList = (From x In Line.Split(","c) Select CInt(x)).ToList
```

Note: Please no debate on CInt() vs Integer.Parse() vs Int32.Parse()